# A list that gets corrupted after passing it to a function

Tags: python-2.7, list

The problem is basically after I call a function with a list that list changes content even though I'm using `list + [something]` which should return a new reference to a new list not the same as list.

example code:

```
def foo(a):
  #modifying the list using del and remove

def bar(b):
  alist = b
  foo(alist + [something])
  #at this point alist != the original alist
```

I also tried making a tmp list using `list(alist)` and `alist + [something]`

Can I use pastebin here to refer to the actual code?

Comment: That shouldn't change `alist`. It may change elements of it, but that isn't *quite* the same thing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Why does it change elements? Aren't we using different list inside the `foo` if thats the case then alist after the return should remain the same.

Comment: You've created a new list, but you haven't created new elements.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams https://pastebin.com/b12Bzd8x In the DPLL function after the call in the if condition in line 64 the content of the original clauses will change. If we returned from that call the state of `clauses` should remain the same, but in my code I get a different list.

Comment: That's the thing: `clauses` *doesn't* change. But its elements do. Line 49.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm passing a new list with different id when I use `clauses + [[L, 0]]` why the elements of `clauses` which shouldn't be related to `clauses + [[L, 0]]` are changing?

Comment: The elements are exactly the same objects both inside and outside the function. Only the list has changed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ohh so its like a different container that holds the same elements as the first container. Whats the best way to go around this? To modify the list then go back to the original list after the return.

Comment: Copy the elements as needed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yup that worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your list `alist` contains some sublists in it. In this case, even if you do `alist + [something]`, you are still passing the pointers to those sublists to function `foo()`.

There is a hard and quick solution to that, simply use python's `deepcopy()` function as follows. This will make a replication of everything in your list in the memory.

```
from copy import deepcopy
def bar(b):
    b_copy = deepcopy(b)
    foo(b_copy)
```